# Проблема с поиском трех минимальных элементов массива

Tags: c#

В общем, есть массив дохода и расхода, от которых формируется массив прибыли. Нужно в массиве прибыли выделить три минимальных элемента. Мой вариант в программе не работает, точнее работает через раз (в одном случае выведет все три одинаковых результата, либо выведет все как положено (min1<min2<min3)). Скриншоты результатов прилагаю.Пробовал заранее отсортировать массив прибыль от наименьшего к большему, а оттуда уже делать выборку....Ну, ничего не получилось. В упор не вижу ошибку. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 using System;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Руководство фирмы по 12 месяцам ведет учет расходов и поступлений средств. 
        // За год получены два массива – расходов и поступлений.
        // Определить прибыли по месяцам
        // Количество месяцев с положительной прибылью.
        // Добавить возможность вывода трех худших показателей по месяцам, с худшей прибылью, 

        // Выводим Заголовки колонок базы данных
        Console.WriteLine($"{"Месяц",15} {"Доход, тыс.руб",15} {"Расход, тыс.руб",10} {"Прибыль, тыс.руб",15}");
        //Генератор случайных чисел для автоматическое заполения колонок прибыли и расходов
        Random r = new Random();
        //Инициализация ступенчатого массива
        int[][] finance = new int[12][];
        //Инициализация вспомогательного массива
        int[] tempArray = new int[12];

        for (int j = 0; j < finance.Length; j++)
        {
            finance[j] = new int[3]; //создание 3 дополнительных массивов
        }
        //Заполнение массива БД
        for (int i = 0; i < finance.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write($"{i + 1,15}");
            for (int j = 0; j < finance[i].Length; j++)
            {
                finance[i][0] = r.Next(1, 10); //Генерация данных прибыли
                finance[i][1] = r.Next(1, 6); //Генерация данных расходов
            }
            finance[i][2] = finance[i][0] - finance[i][1]; //Расчет прибыли
            for (int j = 0; j < finance[i].Length; j++)
            {
                Console.Write($"{finance[i][j],15}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        //Вычленение "Прибыли" в отдельный массив
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < finance.Length; i++)
        {
            temp = finance[i][2];
            tempArray[i] = temp;
        }

        //Меню функций
        Console.WriteLine("Меню операция с БД:\n1 - показать месяцы с отрицательной прибылью\n2 - показать месяцы с худшей прибылью");
        int choose;
        for (; ; )
        {
            choose = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (choose > 3 || choose <= 0) Console.WriteLine("Некорректный ввод");
            else break;
        }
        //Реализация функций
        switch(choose)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.Write("Список месяцев с отрицательной прибылью: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (tempArray[i] < 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write($"{i + 1,3} ");
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            break;

            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("Худшая прибылью: ");
                //Создание массива результатов по прибыли
                int[] result = new int[3];
                //Поиск трех минмальных значений массива
                int min1 = 0, min2 = 0, min3 = 0;
                for (int i=0; i<tempArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (min1 > tempArray[i])
                    {
                        min3 = min2;
                        min2 = min1;
                        min1 = tempArray[i];
                    }
                    else if (min2 > tempArray[i])
                    {
                        min3 = min2;
                        min2 = tempArray[i];
                    }
                    else if (min3>tempArray[i])
                    {
                        min3 = tempArray[i];
                    }
                }
                //Вывод результатов
                result[0] = min1;
                result[1] = min2;
                result[2] = min3;
                Console.WriteLine();
                for (int i=0; i<result.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write($"{result[i],3}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `int[] result = tempArray.OrderBy(x=>x).Take(3).ToArray();` ?

Comment: судя по картинкам, вы находите 3 мин значения из последнего столбца. Что не так?

Comment: `int min1 = 0, min2 = 0, min3 = 0;` полагаю, что тут надо давать переменным другие значения, например, первые 3 значения из вашей таблицы. Ведь если у вас изначально не будет отрицательной прибыли, то эти значения так и не будут переписаны.

Comment: @tym32167 Проблема в том, что в некоторых результатах появляются одинаковые значения. Такого быть не должно

Comment: `в некоторых результатах появляются одинаковые значения` - пример? Предлагаете гадать что у вас получается? Все нули поди?

Comment: @tym32167
Пример 1: {7,4,8,4,4,0,5,3,-3,2,3,-1} Результат {-3,-1,0}
Пример 2: {1,6,2,5,4,4,-3,4,3,3,3,0} Результат {-3,-3,0}, а должно {-3,0,1}

Comment: первый вроде верный, нет? Во втором откуда 1 появится, если у вас все минимумы изначально нули?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сортировка всего массива для получения трех минимальных элементов нерациональна, особенно если массив велик.

Ведь для получения одного максимума мы обычно не сортируем, вот и для трех можно обойтись одним проходом:

```
Заводим массив M[3], заполняем заведомо большим числом или тремя копиями значения первого элемента
Проходим в цикле по остальным элементам:
    Для текущего элемента X определяем, 
    можно ли его вставить в сортированный массив M (ищем место вставки)
         Если да, то сдвигаем соответствующее количество элементов M 
         (при этом один удаляется) 
         и вставляем X
```

Comment: Можно было и так) Осознание этого пришло уже после моего решения...

Answer (score 0):

В общем, нашел я решение. В куске кода описывается как взять три минимальных числа через предварительную сортировку массива, а также с последующим анализом на повторяющиеся значения. При такой сортировке элемент [0] остается на месте.
Далее после чего, необходимо записать первые три элемента отсортированного массива в результаты.
Думаю, есть и более лаконичное решение, но пока что лучше не придумал

```
                case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("Худшая прибыль: ");
                //Создание массива результатов по прибыли
                int[] result = new int[3];
                //Сортировка таблицы прибыли
                Array.Sort(tempArray);
                //Поиск трех минмальных значений массива
                int count = 1;
                for (int i = 1; i < tempArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (tempArray[i] != tempArray[i-1])
                    {
                        tempArray[count] = tempArray[i];
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                //Запись результатов в массив
                for (int i=0; i<result.Length; i++)
                {
                    result[i] = tempArray[i];
                    Console.Write($"{result[i],3}");
                }
                //Вывод месяцев с худшей прибылью
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Список месяцев с худшей прибылью");
                for (int i=0; i<finance.Length; i++)
                {
                    int month = 0;
                    for (int j=0; j<result.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (finance[i][2] <= result[j]) month=i+1;
                    }
                    if (month>0) Console.Write($"{month,3}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

                break;
```

Comment: Код лучше выровнять, большие лишние отступы затрудняют чтение и снижают качество вашего ответа.